# how to move from a fragment in recyclerview to another activity ? the intent is showing "app has stopped"

Tags: android

MyAdapter.java the java file is having errors in the intent part, the app is stopping in emulator.

[image]

Comment: post the logcat error

Comment: Welcome to *StackOverFlow*.

Comment: post the code of MyHolder class.

Answer (score 0):

May be you did not register the *second activity* in **Manifest.xml** file !

Answer (score 0):

Try using FragmentActivity in place of Context. It might be the solution.